# Making a file accessible to scripts but not users

Tags: php

I have uploaded scripts to users servers. I don't want others to access this script through the browser, However, I want a script to be able to access it.

Placing the file outside of the public_html is not an option here,because it really needs to be in the public_html. Any ideas??? thanks.

Comment: Why does it need to be in public_html?

Comment: @Fosco the OP is probably on some server that only has user rights to `public_html`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put some variable before the include so you know where it is being called:

index.php:

```
$open = true;
include 'open.php';
```

open.php:

```
<?php
   if(isset($open) && $open){
      //do what it is supposed to do 
   }
   else {
      header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
      exit;
   }
?>
```

Comment: I'm going to up-vote this as, now that you've posted it, I think this is what they're meaning (but were a little vague). Similar to what big projects like phpBB do, this would allow other scripts to include it, but no direct access.

Comment: I do this all the time.. very neat and effective solution

Comment: @Neal How to achieve this in Laravel Framework 5.3? I need to achieve the same but because its a framework I dont know how can I do the variable thing in View or Controller and have header with 403 forbidden

Comment: I have no idea @MurlidharFichadia

Answer (score 5):

If by scripts you mean server-side, you can add a `.htaccess` file in the folder concerned:

```
deny from all
```

If however by script you mean client-side, then ultimately you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the path accessible only to authenticated clients and provide the credentials only to your script.

If it's to be accessed through the browser, then users and scripts are both "clients" and you cannot differentiate between them (except using flimsy tricks like user agent sniffing etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Making a file accessible to users or sripts is pretty much synonymous. You're not going to get one without the other. Users can **always** mimic scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The included php file that you want to keep away from users can be placed outside your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and still be included in your other scripts.

That way included php file can never be accessed by your web users. In fact that is a good secured way of storing your database connection credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to put it outside of the public_html directory.  There should be no reason that is HAS to be in the public_html directory if only your script is going to access it.